# How to I format an integer with leading 0's in javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to format a string so that it looks like:

"Expect 000062" in javascript.

In C# I do this:

```
String expect = String.Format("Expect {0:000000}", data.Length);
```

In Swift I do this:

```
var expect = NSString(format: "Expect %06d", data.length)
```

How do I do this same thing in javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Zerofilled value using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1267283/how-can-i-create-a-zerofilled-value-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var Num = "64";
var nNum = ("000000" + Num).slice(-6);
console.log(nNum);
```